# More efficient Python script for determining if many files exist in a directory and nested subdirectories

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, hash, directory

I am looking for an algorithm that takes a long list of filepaths, checks if each exists in a file directory, and returns a list of those that are not somewhere in the directory.

*There are many questions asking how to look for a single file in a directory* and its subdirectories but these do not scale when searching for hundreds or thousands of files in a directory or subdirectory as the solution to these questions involves using os.walk for each search. Either one iterates over the entire directory for every file in question or iterates over the list of files for every directory. I will be looking through a large directory tree so it would take a long time to do that for every file. I am thinking the most efficient solution is to iterate over the directory structure once and build dictionaries from the files.

My current efforts have been to crawl the entire directory structure and building dictionaries. For one dictionary, the key is the size of the file and the values are lists of files with that size. The other dictionary is the key is the hash of the file and the value is a list of paths for all the files with that hash.
I then iterate over all the files in the file list to see if their key is in size_dict.keys() or hash_dict.keys(). If it is, I remove it from the list of files. Here is **pseudocode** that expresses what I have done:

```
def file_hunter(list_of_files, search_directory):
    size_dict = defaultdict(list)
    hash_dict = defaultdict(list)
    #populate dictionaries with files in the search_directory
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(search_directory):
        for search_file in files:
           add_file_to_dictionaries(search_file)
    #iterate over  list_of_files and check them against the populated dictionaries
    for file in list_of_files:
        if not size_dict[file.size]:
           list_of_files.remove(file)
        else: #trying to avoid having to hash every file
            if not hash_dict[hash(file)]:
                list_of_files.remove(file)
            else:
                continue
    return list_of_files #returning list of files not in search_directory
```

...where list_of_files is a list of paths to files that I want to look for and search_directory is the path to the directory where i want to look for the files.
I will be running this script on file lists and directories of varying sizes but they will mostly all be pretty big. Any tips for how to make this more efficient?

Comment: can you explain what you are doing with an example

Comment: Also please provide an expected/got output.

Comment: I am getting the list of files that I am expecting but it is taking too long to run the script.